# Django - 'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

In this specific part of my Django project, I am trying to return a dict containing QuerySet of objects that I have filtered through so that these objects can be used in the template they are passed to. Below is my code:

**In views.py**

```
def shows_in_category(request, category_slug):
 category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
 print(category_slug)
 shows = theShow.objects.filter(category__name=category).all()
 print(shows)
 return render(request, 'show/show_list_view.html', {'shows': shows})
```

**In models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
 name = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)
 slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)


 class Meta:
  verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

 def __str__(self):
  return self.name

 def get_absolute_url(self):
  return reverse("theshowapp:shows_in_category", args=[self.slug])

class theShow(models.Model):
 english_name = models.CharField(max_length=400)
 show_type = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
 category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
 slug = models.SlugField(max_length=400,unique=True)

 class Meta:
  verbose_name_plural = 'Shows Series'

 def __str__(self):
  return self.english_name
```

Here is the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\danie\miniconda3\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "C:\Users\danie\miniconda3\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\danie\OneDrive\Documents\streamingsitetest\showing\views.py", line 
14, in shows_in_category
return render(request, 'show_templates/show_list_view.html', {'shows': 
shows})
File "C:\Users\danie\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 
19, in render
content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, 
using=using)
File "C:\Users\danie\miniconda3\lib\site- 
packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
return template.render(context, request)
File "C:\Users\danie\miniconda3\lib\site- 
packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
return self.template.render(context)
File "C:\Users\danie\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", 
line 170, in render
return self._render(context)
File "C:\Users\danie\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", 
line 162, in _render
return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Users\danie\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", 
line 938, in render
bit = node.render_annotated(context)
File "C:\Users\danie\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", 
line 905, in render_annotated
return self.render(context)
File "C:\Users\danie\miniconda3\lib\site- 
packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "C:\Users\danie\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", 
line 162, in _render
return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Users\danie\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", 
line 938, in render
bit = node.render_annotated(context)
File "C:\Users\danie\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", 
line 905, in render_annotated
return self.render(context)
File "C:\Users\danie\miniconda3\lib\site- 
packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Users\danie\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", 
line 938, in render
bit = node.render_annotated(context)
File "C:\Users\danie\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", 
line 905, in render_annotated
return self.render(context)
File "C:\Users\danie\miniconda3\lib\site- 
packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 211, in render
nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
File "C:\Users\danie\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", 
line 905, in render_annotated
return self.render(context)
File "C:\Users\danie\miniconda3\lib\site- 
packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 167, in render
values = list(values)

Exception Type: TypeError at /shows/action
Exception Value: 'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable
```

I understand from previous questions similar to mine that I needed to make `shows` a QuerySet so that it is iterable which is why I added `.all()` to the end of its definition. I used print(type(shows)) and ensured that a QuerySet was created and I'm still receiving this error. What can I do to make it so that I can iterate through `shows`?

Comment: Please post the *full* traceback.

Comment: Those are objects.  What information from those objects did you want to return?  And by the way, you wanted `print(type(shows))`, not `print(shows.type())`.

Comment: Maybe you want to use `shows.show_type()` bc this is the variables name?

Comment: Why are you printing the category and the "type"? Just comment out those lines.

Comment: @bimmui  Your question and your title do not seem to match up btw.

Comment: What exactly you want to do here? in other words, what are you going to retrieve?

Comment: Just updated my post to make it clear on what exactly I'm trying to do and the exact part I need help with. Also, @WillemVanOnsem, I added a full traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

`shows = theShow.objects.filter(category__name=category).all()`

I used this line of code to instead return a dictionary instead of a QuerySet of objects.

`shows = animeShow.objects.filter(category__name=category).values()`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you looking(assumed) for is the [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#related-objects) attribute which used in reverse relation

> If you don't specify a [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#related-objects), Django automatically creates one
> using the name of your model with the suffix _set, for instance
> theshow_set

so what you have to do here is,

```
class theShow(models.Model):
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='theshow_Set')
    ...
```

and when you querying,

```
category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug).theshow_set.all()
```

---

**Note**: I assumed this is what you intended to do.